# Scala: Quicksort for a MutableList[Array[Double]]

Tags: arrays, list, scala, quicksort

I'm using a `MutableList[Array[Double]]`, of which every Array holds five Doubles.

Now I want to implement a quicksort which sorts the List according to its Array's n-th Column. I've looked at the quicksort example on Rosetta, and came up with this adaption:

```
def quicksortDataByIndex(index: Int, list: MutableList[Array[Double]]): MutableList[Array[Double]] = {
    if(list.isEmpty){
      list
    } else {      
      val(smaller, bigger) = list partition (_(index) > list.head(index))
      quicksortDataByIndex(index, smaller) += list.head ++= quicksortDataByIndex(index, bigger)
    }
  }
}
```

Which throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception at the n-th element.

I assume that writing '_(index)' is wrong, but I don't know why, and how it could be done differently.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want, I have just added the `.tail` before partitioning.

```
def quicksortDataByIndex(index: Int, list: MutableList[Array[Double]]) : MutableList[Array[Double]] = {
  if(list.isEmpty){
    list
  } else {      
    val (smaller, bigger) = list.tail partition (a => a(index) < list.head(index))
    quicksortDataByIndex(index, smaller) += list.head ++= quicksortDataByIndex(index, bigger)
  }
}
```

Output :

```
quicksortDataByIndex(1, MutableList(Array(0, 3), Array(1, 2), Array(0, 7)))
// MutableList(Array(1.0, 2.0), Array(0.0, 3.0), Array(0.0, 7.0))
```

Comment: Thanks! I still get the same exception though. In my code, I am using a MutableList[Array[String]], since it's all read from a file, so I added a .toDouble: `(a => a(index).toDouble > list.head(index).toDouble)`. Could that be the source of the error? Edit: I can't convert all the strings in the array to doubles, since the first entries of the array are names, not values.

Comment: Nevermind, another error was hidden in the file! Thank you!